# Validate firewalld config with ansible

Tags: linux, ansible, firewalld

I'm using ansible to configure firewalld.

The [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) module has a `validate` parameter, which I'd like to use to validate my config.

I tried this:

```yaml
- name: config firewalld
  become: true
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf
    regexp: "^#?FirewallBackend"
    line: "FirewallBackend=iptables"
    state: present
    validate: firewall-cmd --check-config         # <--------------
```

But I get an ansible error:

> validate must contain %s: firewall-cmd --check-config

That's because it's expecting the path to the file (`%s`).

I consulted [the docs](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewall-cmd.html#status_options) for `--check-config` to find a way to specify the config file's path, but couldn't find anything.

*Is there a way to do this?* I could run a raw `sudo firewall-cmd --check-config`, but I'm hoping there's a native ansible way to do this.

Comment: I suspect this is not possible, so I added a feature request to [the repo](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/1126). Please upvote it if you also want this functionality.

Comment: You can also apply a scenario for [more complex validations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#complex-configuration-validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From detail on [the repo](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/1126), looks like this isn't possible to do cleanly with ansible. So here's a workaround:

```yaml
- name: modify config
  become: true
    # ...
  register: result1

- name: modify config
  become: true
    # ...
  register: result2

- name: modify config
  become: true
    # ...
  register: result3

- name: validate config
  become: true
  command: firewall-cmd --check-config              
  when: result1 is changed or result2 is changed or result3 is changed
  notify: "reload firewalld"
```